# JS Regex: Wrap content in multiple tags defined in appended lines?

Tags: javascript, regex

I’m trying to replace content using JavaScript String replace as follows:

From:

```
line 1
line 2
! foo
! bar
! baz
```

To:

```
<baz>
<bar>
<foo>line 1</foo>
<foo>line 2</foo>
</bar>
</baz>
```

I.e., wrap every line in a block in the first “!” tag, wrap remaining tags around the whole block. Should obviously work for 1+ content and “!” lines.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this in one step using capture groups, or would this require something more complex?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can match the parts, do the splits, then construct it to what you want.

```
/^((?:(?!\r?\n!)[\S\s])+)\s*\r?\n![ \t]*(.+)\s*\r?\n![ \t]*((?:(?!\s*\r?\n!)[\S\s](?:\s*\r?\n![ \t]*)?)+)/
```

https://regex101.com/r/Ji5ys6/1

Group 1 = lines, split on `\s*\r?\n\s*`
Group 2 = *foo*
Group 3 = *bar, baz,...*  split on `\s*!\s*`

```
 ^ 
 (                             # (1 start), line1, line 2, ...
      (?:
           (?! \r? \n ! )
           [\S\s] 
      )+
 )                             # (1 end)
 \s* \r? \n ! [ \t]* 
 ( .+ )                        # (2), foo
 \s* \r? \n ! [ \t]* 
 (                             # (3 start), bar, baz, ...
      (?:
           (?! \s* \r? \n ! )
           [\S\s] 
           (?: \s* \r? \n ! [ \t]* )?
      )+
 )                             # (3 end)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but looking at the regex101.com example you gave, this doesn’t seem to work. Capture Group 1 is “line 1 line2”, Group 3 is “bar! baz”. I was looking for a way to wrap each regular line (1, 2) _individually_ in the first ^! line tag (foo), then the whole group in the subsequent tags / groups (bar, baz). I didn’t claim it’s possible, though – I have been writing regular expressions in BBEdit for 15 years and couldn’t get it to work…

Comment: @Wintermute101 - You can do it in a single replace using a callback function. You get the match variables, groups 1,2,3. Do the splits as indicated above, Loop through the arrays and construct the replacement string, which you return. It's that easy. They used to have JS code snips you can run here, but I guess no more, I'd show you how to do it.

Comment: I’m not a coder myself beyond knowing a few bits about regular expressions, so I’m afraid you lost me at “looping through arrays”. But I’ll take this to someone who knows what he’s doing to complete this task. Thanks a lot for helping with this!